# How do I setup android application using Eclipse in Ubuntu?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I downloaded the ADT Bundle and extracted as required, but when i want to create an android application, such an option does not exist.

Comment: What do you mean? Create an Android project, export an apk, ...?

Answer (score 2):

Use the following steps:

go to window--Preferences--Android

then give your android sdk path

in my case:

like:/home/ravindmaurya/AndroidTa/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130729/sdk

then press apply

Comment: The preferences doesnt have an android tab! :/

Answer (score 0):

Your SDK is not Configured therefore you can not create Android Project, First you have to configure Android SDK in Preferences like I am showing you in the below Snapshot 
[image]

Now You will find **Create Android Application** Options
[image]

Download ADT from [this link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#ExistingIDE)

[image]

Comment: For some reason there is no Android option in my preferences..

Comment: This means You dont have android SDK. Without SDK These Options can not be accessed.

Comment: I downloaded and extracted this zipped file. http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20131030.zip,which is the same as the link posted above.

Comment: Yeah You are on the right track, but lets check out the links I posted. and Vote-up if you find it useful

Comment: Ive tried installing this before a while back, and might have set some  path variables differently, I need help to know which ones.:(

Comment: Bro from that ADT Bundles you dont need any settings, dont know why you are facing these issues